# Django signals - multiple requests on same model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-signals, django-middleware

I am using a `pre_save` signal to store the user who performed the last operation on a particular instance.

To achieve this, I'm using a middleware. In the `process_request` function of it, the signal is registered with the appropriate function, `set_user` as shown below.

```
mark_who_did = curry(self.set_user, user)
models.signals.pre_save.connect(
      mark_who_did,
      dispatch_uid=(self.__class__, request,),
      weak=False
)
```

Then, I'm disconnecting this signal in the `process_response` function of the middleware.

```
models.signals.pre_save.disconnect(dispatch_uid=(self.__class__, request,))
```

This works fine when concurrency is not involved. However, suppose we have three concurrent requests - the signal is connected three times, and the `set_user` method is invoked **nine times**, for each user-request combination.

As per my understanding, each request should have been operating independently, but that is obviously not the case. Is there something I'm missing, or is there something I could change in my code to fix this?

Comment: maybe it's because of the dispatch_uid is the same?

Comment: @Hetdev No, the `dispatch_uid` is unique for each request.